# Create PendingIntents in a onItemLongClick ( Context issues )

Tags: android

Hi i'm trying to reproduce pendingIntents in order to cancel them ...

But i don't really understand how the context, getBaseContext(), getApplicationContext() really work and what i need ...

The problem is that when i created them it was in a simple function now i'm in a onItemLongClick function from a listView then in a dialogue Interface ...

Here's the code :

**[EDITED] - with ReglagesActivity.this which is my OuterClass but now I've got a java.lang.NullPointerExecption :/
But i tested if my object were null or not so .... :/**

**[EDIT 2] - Just Forget to recreate my alarm_Manager object ... My bad ><**

```
 ListNotifs.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
     public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position, long id) {

            final AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReglagesActivity.this);

            // set title
            b.setTitle("Suppression de l'alarme");

            // set dialog message
            b
            .setMessage("Souhaitez-vous vraiment supprimer cette alarme ?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Oui",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // SUPPRESS

                        // Get number of the alarm :
                        HashMap<String, String> hash = listItem.get(position);
                        String num_str = hash.get("description");
                        String[] spliit = num_str.split(" ");
                        String splited = spliit[spliit.length-1];
                        int num = Integer.parseInt(splited);

                        //Re-create intent for cancel :


                        try {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ReglagesActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
// Here is the probleme for context i tried this : Makes the app crash ^^ :


                            PendingIntent alarm_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ReglagesActivity.this.
                                                getApplicationContext(),num,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);






                                    if ( alarm_intent != null && intent != null )
                                    {

                                    try 
                                    {
                                        alarm_Manager.cancel(alarm_intent);
                                    }
                                    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) 
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "[Erreur] alarme mal supprimée\n\n"+e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
```

Comment: Try something like `OuterClassName.this` instead of `getBaseContext()`. This is a common way of getting the current `Context` from an `Inner Class`.

Comment: hmm still throw an `java.lang.NullPointerException` :/ ... For the first Try / catch so i know it come from the line : `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...)`

Comment: Make sure your "num" and "intent" variables aren't `null`. Also try "`OuterClassName.this.getApplicationContext()`" instead of `getBaseContext().getApplicationContext()` in your `PendingIntent` creation code.

Comment: i put that ^^ And i add `if( alarm_intent != null && intent != null )`

But still nullPointer hooooow ?

Comment: Omg my bad i didn't recreate alarm_Manager object ! >< ... But thanks for the `OuterClassNam.this` it's very helpfull for me :)

Comment: If I helped you, you should give me an up-vote ;]

Comment: I wanted to but not enought reputation :( But if you answer again but not in comment i can say this topic is solved by clicking the tick on your answer ^^